# Calculating the sum of values in a different table for rows that are between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have two tables.

A campagin table:

| Campaign ID | Start Date | End Date | Daily Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21/12/2020 | 15/02/2021 | 5 |
| 2 | 18/10/2020 | 18/01/2021 | 3 |
| 3 | 01/07/2020 | 03/01/2021 | 8 |
| 4 | 09/01/2021 | 15/05/2021 | 1 |
| 5 | 05/08/2020 | 09/01/2021 | 2 |

And a simple Date table:

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/01/2021 |
| 02/01/2021 |
| 03/01/2021 |
| 04/01/2021 |
| 05/01/2021 |
| 06/01/2021 |
| 07/01/2021 |
| 08/01/2021 |
| 09/01/2021 |
| 10/01/2021 |
| 11/01/2021 |
| 12/01/2021 |
| 13/01/2021 |

What I would like to do is add a calculated column to the Date table that will calculate the sum of all the Daily Targets for campaigns that are between Start Date and End Date. So for 1st January 2021 I want to take the sum of the Daily Targets for Campaign 1, 2, 3 & 5. E.g:

| Date | Total Daily Target |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 18 |
| 02/01/2021 | 18 |
| 03/01/2021 | 18 |
| 04/01/2021 | 10 |
| 05/01/2021 | 10 |
| 06/01/2021 | 10 |
| 07/01/2021 | 10 |
| 08/01/2021 | 10 |
| 09/01/2021 | 9 |
| 10/01/2021 | 9 |
| 11/01/2021 | 9 |
| 12/01/2021 | 9 |
| 13/01/2021 | 9 |

I'm quite new to DAX and have tried multiple different variations of SUM(), SUMX() & FILTER() within CALCULATE(), all to no avail. I also don't know what the relationship between the two tables should be seeing as there are two dates in the Campaign table? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below **Measure**-

```
Measure = 

var current_row_date = MIN('date'[Date])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(campaign[Daily Target]),
    campaign[Start Date] <= current_row_date
        && campaign[End Date] >= current_row_date
)
```

output-

[image]